# Vuex's action is unknown

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

My Vue3 application gives me error `[vuex] unknown action type: updateUnit`. There is issue only with action, because getter works fine.

This is file `/store/index.ts` where I have defined my store object.

```
interface State {
  unit: LearningUnit | null
}

const getters: GetterTree<State, any> = {
  unitDictionary: (state: State) => (): Array<Word> => {
    return dictionary
  }
}

const actions: ActionTree<State, any> = {
  async updateUnit ({ commit }, unit: LearningUnit): Promise<void> {
    commit('UPDATE_UNIT', unit)
  }
}

const mutations: MutationTree<State> = {
  UPDATE_UNIT (state, unit: LearningUnit) {
    state.unit = unit
  }
}

export default createStore<State>({
  state: {
    unit: null
  },
  actions: actions,
  mutations: mutations,
  getters: getters
})
```

And this is how I am trying to call my action `updateUnit` from Vue component:

At first I define it in methods:

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions({
    updateUnit: 'updateUnit'
  })
}
```

And then call from watcher like this `this.updateUnit(params.unit)`.

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a namespace? Also, which modules can you see in your Vue devtools? Also, pick one: Vue2 or 3. Not both.

Comment: @kissu I updated question, I am using Vue3. And I checked store by printing this.$store in module, and there is no other modules

Comment: @kissu there is issue only with action because defined getter works fine.

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. Currently looks like it's not. This code is supposed to work, there's no place for mistakes

Comment: Checking the Vue devtools goes a bit further than a `console.log`. Otherwise, it's hard to say what is not working as of right now indeed. Maybe try to re-type your action again (with copypasta) to maybe spot an issue. ESlint/TS are not complaining with your code?

Comment: Does it work if you call `this.$store.dispatch('updateUnit', params.unit)` directly?

Comment: @Kapcash should produce the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kissu sure, it should, but at least it would discard an error with the mapAction method. Also I'm seeing the method is `async` even though it doesn't use `await` inside. But it shouldn't cause this error.